# Can't set localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, local-storage

I have made a login system to verify the password with the username. This is my code:

```js
function verify(e) {
  $("#loginError")[0].innerHTML = ("Name and password must have a value");
  $("#loginError")[0].style.display = "none";
  if ($("#loginName")[0].value != "" && $("#loginPassword")[0].value != "") {
    e.classList.add('loading');
    e.disabled = true;
    var json = {
      name: $("#loginName")[0].value,
      password: $("#loginPassword")[0].value
    };
    e.classList.add('disabled');
    $.get('https://cloud.abaanshanid.repl.co/verifyacc', json, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.includes("name") == true) {
        e.classList.remove('loading');
        e.disabled = false;
        e.classList.remove('disabled');
        console.log("User there");
        window.localStorage.setItem("loginInfo", data);
      } else if (data == "404") {
        $("#loginError")[0].innerHTML = ("This accout doesn't exist!")
        $("#loginError")[0].style.display = "block";
        e.classList.remove('loading');
        e.disabled = false;
        e.classList.remove('disabled');
      } else {
        $("#loginError")[0].innerHTML = ("Wrong password!")
        $("#loginError")[0].style.display = "block";
        e.classList.remove('loading');
        e.disabled = false;
        e.classList.remove('disabled');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#loginError")[0].style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

After the request the server returns the user data if the password is correct, I want to save the user info in localStorage, but I can't save the data for some reason. The browser doesn't show any errors either.

Comment: Using jQuery to retrieve an object then using native JS methods on that object is very odd. Use jQuery properly if you're going to select elements with it, eg. `$("#loginName").val() != ''`, `$("#loginError").html('Name and password must have a value').hide();`

Answer (score 2):

Local storage can only have strings, if you need to set "data" then you have to parse it, try: `window.localStorage.setItem("loginInfo", JSON.stringify(data));`

You can read it back with `JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("loginInfo"))`.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for helping! I have tried this before, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AbaanShanid This is a correct answer on how to store objects in localstorage, could you check what your data serializes to? console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: Sorry to hear that, may i know what the output of `console.log(data)` shows?

Comment: Ok it's my bad, I use Mozilla Firefox. It doesn't show the data in the storage tab but when I type  `localStorage.getItem("loginInfo")`  to the console I get that data,